# Problema Creacion Tabla en Transact-SQL en SQL-Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy creando 4 tablas bastantes simples en Management Studio con las entidades de:

```
Alumno (PK_idUsuario, nombreUsuario)
Clase (PK_idClase, nombreClase)
Salon (PK_idSalon, numeroSalon, FK_idClase)
AlumnoClase (FK_idClase, FK_idAlumno)
```

y en la creacion de las primeras 3 tablas no tengo ningun inconveniente en crearla, pero en la ultima me tira este error:

```
**PERFECTO**
    CREATE TABLE Alumno(
    PK_idUsuario INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreUsuario VARCHAR(150),
    )
    
**PERFECTO**
    CREATE TABLE Clase(
    PK_idClase INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreClase VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    )
    
**PERFECTO**
    CREATE TABLE Salon(
    PK_idSalon INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreSalon VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    FK_idClase INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idClase FOREIGN KEY (FK_idClase) REFERENCES Clase (PK_idClase)
    )
    
**ERROR**
    CREATE TABLE AlumnoClaseCombinacion(
    FK_idUsuario INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idUsuario FOREIGN KEY (FK_idUsuario) REFERENCES Alumno (PK_idUsuario),
    FK_idClase INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idClase FOREIGN KEY (FK_idClase) REFERENCES Clase (PK_idClase)
    )
```

EL ERROR:

```
Msg 2714, Level 16, State 5, Line 21
There is already an object named 'FK_idClase' in the database.
Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
```

Estuve viendo un monton de sitios, pero no pude encontrar una solucion, muchos hacen uso del diagrama para realizar las relaciones, pero no me queda claro que estoy haciendo mal. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la tabla `Salon`ya estas usando el nombre `FK_idClase`por lo tanto en `AlumnoClaseCombinacion`ya no te permite nuevamente usarlo.

Cambia `FK_idClase` de nombre o agrega otro caracter para que sea diferente en la tabla `AlumnoClaseCombinacion`.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Mi sugerencia (no soy DBA, es como he visto lo manejan):

```
CREATE TABLE Alumno(
    idUsuario INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreUsuario VARCHAR(150),
)
    
CREATE TABLE Clase(
    idClase INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreClase VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
)
    
CREATE TABLE Salon(
    idSalon INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreSalon VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    idClase INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idClase_Salon_Clase FOREIGN KEY (idClase) REFERENCES Clase (idClase)
)
    
CREATE TABLE AlumnoClaseCombinacion(
    idUsuario INT NOT NULL,
    idClase INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_idUsuario_AlumnoClaseCombinacion_Alumno FOREIGN KEY (idUsuario) REFERENCES Alumno (idUsuario),
    CONSTRAINT FK_idClase_AlumnoClaseCombinacion_Clase FOREIGN KEY (idClase) REFERENCES Clase (idClase)
)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Roberto, y usualmente como se nombran por convencion? En la tabla `Salon`le dejo `FK_IdClase `y en la tabla  `AlumnoClaseCombinacion `que le pondrias para detectar que es la  `PK_idClase`?

Comment: Dentro de la longitud que permita la BD en uso; el nombre del campo en la tabla tal cual esta declarado como PK; su `CONSTRAINT` los inicio con `FK` de ahi el nombre del campo (de la tabla donde crearas el `CONSTRAINT`) `ìdClase`seguido de la tabla donde se declara y luego de la tabla que se hace referencia; sería algo como `FK_IdClase_AlumnoClase_Clase` (esto si el campo lo declaras `ìdClase`; en tu código ya lo nombreas `FK_idClase`).

Comment: Roberto, como lo harías vos en definitiva sobre el código de arriba donde esta la creación de las 4 tablas, porque no estoy entendiendo eso, y como ingresarlo! Gracias

Comment: Lo pruebo y te aviso Roberto!!! Mil gracias